# how to https hosting in python http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using python http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler to create an http server using below code

```
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
     print("serving at port", str(PORT))
     httpd.serve_forever()
```

We want this server to be accessed via https, so I found one solution online below is the code snippet for it

```
import http.server, ssl

server_address = ('localhost', 4443)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                               server_side=True,
                               certfile='localhost.pem',
                               ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The problem for this approach is that, we will host is on many client machines and it should happen dynamically, so how can we generate the ssl certificates dynamically, and is there any way to host the server as https without providing any certificate file via this method.

Comment: Which OS you will be using? and no you can't serve https without a certificate. however you can generate a certificate in each machine using openssl

Comment: For this dynamic scenario I recommend binding the Python server to localhost and running it without TLS (plain HTTP). Then put a Caddy webserver (https://caddyserver.com/)  in reverse proxy mode in front of it, it will automatically fetch Let's Encrypt certs for you and refresh them.

Comment: @Equinox openssl requires installation on the machine, can we generate the certificate without installing open ssl on that machine

Comment: Yeah that is why i wanted to ask which os. since openssl is available by default on linux. and with windows you can ship the binary if you really want. Vaizki solution looks good as well but you might want to go that route

Comment: @Equinox we are using windows, but cannot find any good resource on how to get the binary and documentation to use it.

Comment: There is no "official" binary but other people publish binaries. https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries