# View/export localstorage locally in Chrome for a domain that has been 301 redirected?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

A site I use has suddenly moved to a new domain. The old site 301 redirects to the new site. All my settings for the site have been lost, because they are stored in localstorage on the old domain.

Normally, if I need to view everything in localstorage, I go to the site and open developer tools, and there it is.

However, if I try that now, I can only see the new empty localstorage on the new origin, which does not help me at all.

**How do I view the localstorage of a site that I cannot load?**

I tried interrupting the redirect by:

- Disabling redirects in Chrome settings for this domain (no effect)
- Hitting ESC while it loads (failed after repeated attempts)
- Writing a Tampermonkey script (never runs)
- `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; }, false)` (stops, but devtools localstorage never shows old domain, even if I step through)

At no point am I stopped on the previous domain, allowing me to view the associated localstorage.

But I *can* see that it still exists if I go to Chrome's settings | All cookies and site data, and filter for the domain. But, unlike cookies (whose contents are viewable from this settings page), the only things localstorage tells me here are the origin, the size on disk, and the last modified date. Not the contents. But this IS something stored on my computer somehow, and I *should* be able to access it, right?

How do I browse the contents of localstorage *locally*, on my local machine?

- Is there a way to redirect dev tools to a specific domain?
- Is there a way of "tricking" the browser into thinking I'm on a specific domain, so that I can then open dev tools and view the localstorage like normal?
- Or is there an obvious way to browse localstorage that I'm just overlooking?

Comment: Add an override in your [hosts](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) file for this domain and point it to a localhost server with an empty page.

Comment: Success! wOxxOm had the right idea. I'll write up all the steps I took in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on wOxxOm's solution:

For context, I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with Python3 and mkcert already installed.

1. Edit the hosts file

```bash
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

I add a new line at the bottom: `127.0.0.1    (the domain I'm trying to recover)`

Now, I don't have anything running on port 80, so for a regular website I could have run:

```bash
sudo python3 -m http.server 80
```

(sudo because Ubuntu will complain that I don't have permissions to use that port otherwise)

But here's the twist: Nothing showed up in localstorage when I did that. Why? Because the original site wasn't on `http`, it was on `https`.

2. Move to a folder you can leave files in.

I moved to my development folder

3. Generate local certificate

```bash
mkcert (target domain)
mkcert -install
```

This makes a couple files in this folder, `whateverdomain.pem` and `whateverdomain-key.pem`.

4. Write a small python wrapper (from [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70782710/how-to-https-hosting-in-python-http-server-simplehttprequesthandler))

```py
import http.server, ssl

server_address = ('localhost', 443)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                               server_side=True,
                               certfile='whatever.pem',
                               keyfile='whatever-key.pem',
                               ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Server address is 443 for `https`, keyfile is included with certfile.

5. Run the new script

```bash
sudo python3 simpleserver.py
```

Sudo again, because of using a main port.

6. Open the target domain in the browser.
7. Open dev tools. Right-click on the page and choose "Inspect" or use the keyboard shortcut `ctrl-shift-i`
8. Go to the `Application` tab.

Success! My localstorage is finally viewable. From here I was able to copy out the values I needed.

We're done, so clean up:

9. Stop python script.
10. Finally, re-edit `/etc/hosts` and remove or comment out the redirect line.

Was there a simpler way I could have run `https`? Maybe. But this wasn't difficult to set up, and I did recover my inaccessible localstorage, and that's the important thing.

Comment: Might be useful in step 8: [export Data in localStorage for later re-import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13335967)